# Chrome Margin Error

Tags: css

A website I manage: http://www.charisbiblecollege.org.uk/

In Chrome, seems to have a gap between the footer and the bottom of the page.  There is a white space there.  It's not big but it's really bugging me.

I think it's connected to the `margin: 0;` and `width: 100%` on the `<body>` tags, can anyone explain/help?

It doesn't seem to happen in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by rule `div.row:after` where you add as a content `.`. There are 4 simple fixes, use want you need. The ideal will be probably the first one, `content: ''`. Below I put all options you have.

1. You can put there just a blank string, `content: ''`, or `font-size: 0`.

   ```
   div.row:after {content: ''; ...} /* OR */
   div.row:after {font-size: 0; ...}
   ```
2. Or put `overflow: hidden` to this rule:

   ```
   div.row:after {overflow: hidden}
   ```
3. Or put `overflow: hidden` to `#wrap`:

   ```
   #wrap {overflow: hidden}
   ```

Comment: Cool! Can you explain why/how that was happening? it wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: It's caused by rule `div.row:after` where you add as a `content` `.`. Maybe you can put there just a blank string, `content: ''` (style.css, line 27). Or put `overflow: hidden` to this rule.

Comment: Aah, so it was caused by my .clearfix rule?  Either way thank you very much, I wouldnt have worked that out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

div.row:after made the white space, I also see it in firefox.
Change `content: ".";` to `content: "";`

```
div.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
div.row:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

to

```
div.row:after {
clear: both;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

for more info check the [clearfix-hack article](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)